# WPF Context Sensitive Menu Ribbon

Tags: wpf, menu, ribbon

im a bit new to wpf.

im trying to make the acclaimed Ribbon the center for all menus and commands of my custom app

now my main window is a tabcontrol with a few major tabs: contacts,  sales, appointments,expense etc.

on top of the tabcontrol is a ribbon

(pretty similar to MS Outlook)

for each tab i have different buttons that i need

(the tabs each display a different UserControl as its main content)

plus there are several buttons that should always be in the ribbon (settings, about, new appointment...)

the best would be if i can add the RibbonTabs directly in the usercontrols and somehow merge them auto-magically with the main ribbon at runtime depending on the visible tab

if thats not possible then there is something called  ContextualTabGroups, but for the life of me cant find any info on how to bind/trigger the different ribbons to certain cirmcumstances/childcontrols or whatever.

if i need to call .visibilty upon load and close of each usercontrol, then theres nothing "contextual" about that

thank you very much